# Why does my facebook login redirect url still using my docker container name?

Tags: django, docker, facebook-login, django-allauth

I am developing django web application, using django-allauth in a docker environment. In my facebook login redirect URI, I already set the value to be my website URL (https://whizkids.id). But somehow in the redirect URL return by facebook, it change to my docker container name: `web`.

```
https://web.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fweb%2Faccounts%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&client_id=2180006765347725&scope&state=xp0mwKV8NW5w&response_type=code&_rdc=1&_rdr
```

The part `redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fweb%2Faccounts%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F` should be `redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwhizkids.id%2Faccounts%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F`

I am using nginx + letsencrypt configuration below:

```
 upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 8000;
    server_name whizkids.id www.whizkids.id;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}

server {

    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name whizkids.id www.whizkids.id;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/whizkids.id/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key          /etc/letsencrypt/live/whizkids.id/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers '...';

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /src/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }

}
```

Is there any configuration that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/598202/make-nginx-to-pass-hostname-of-the-upstream-when-reverseproxying) you need to set the Host header, either static or dynamic, such as

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 8000;
    server_name whizkids.id www.whizkids.id;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}

server {

    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name whizkids.id www.whizkids.id;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/whizkids.id/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key          /etc/letsencrypt/live/whizkids.id/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers '...';

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /src/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host; // or whizkids.id
    }

}
```

Comment: Love it! That's exactly what I did, using this https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/85

Thanks, appreciate it!